# Keep MySQL schema in sync between computers

Tags: mysql

When developing, I can use SVN or Git to keep code in sync between machines. However, I have been unable to find something similar for MySQL. Does anyone know of anything?

Update: I am trying to get the schema changes across machines. Getting the data to sync as well would be great but is not as important at the moment.

Comment: As in keep multiple copies of a database (one copy per machine) synchronised?  For what purpose?

Comment: What's your priority: the table schema or the data?

Comment: Rather than continually export/import the DB between machines each time it is updated during development, it would be nice if they could be synced. The schema is all I am worried about; getting the data to sync as well would be a bonus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data is not considered a part of your "application source". The schema (ie definition of the tables, indexes etc) should be considered part of your source, although many people do not bother when it comes to MySQL.

If you need to keep data syncronised, you should look at replication scenarios.

See this [about replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) for MySQL

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

- [How to Set Up Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use replication (haven't dealt with this with MySQL before, personally), you're better off using some sort of script to do a mysqldump and commit the backup each time.

You might even be able do it with a git hook to have it automatically dump it out and commit it before a push.

Comment: That would be nice..would there be a way to have it update the receiving/pulling in automatically?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Replication is the way to go here.

Keep an eye on the data both sides of replication as MySQL doesn't offer synchronous replication (yet).

There's a comprehensive toolset to monitor your replication (and more) called Maatkit. This allows you to compare checksums of your data and sync if there are discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/reduardo7/db-version-updater

Script to keep the verion of the database model updated, using a simple Linux script.

This script creates an auxiliar Database Table to register the executed scripts, and prevent to execute any executed script.

--

https://github.com/reduardo7/db-version-updater-mysql

Keep the verion of the database model updated, using a MySQL script.

With this script, you can keep the version of the database model without needing another tool than MySQL console.

It is the simplest and easiest way to perform this task so common, without the need to using other extra tools.

To work, creates an auxiliar database table (database_version) to register the executed scripts, and prevent to execute any executed script.