# Ideal Git setup for multi-platform WordPress development

Tags: wordpress, git, svn

I fear this is a repeat question? I'm a one-man shop working between PC and Mac, and am looking for the best way to subversion or Git my WordPress site/theme/plugin development. I'm open to trying anything out there. I have no need to collaborate, just trying to simplify my workflow and avoid FTP'ing everything every time. :)

**I need a setup that will:**

a) sync changes / commits / versions between my mac and pc (similar to a dropbox setup)

b) enable me to commit changes (including MySQL db changes) to a remote server for client approval

c) revert to previous versions of a site when changes go awry.

d) because not every client will have Git or SVN enabled, I plan on zipping and FTP'ing the final product to the client's server/webhost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much any version control system will do what you want, other than the "automatic sync" component...typically, you will have to manually run something like `git pull` or `svn update` in your working copy in order to bring it up-to-date.

Either Subversion or Git will let you have multiple working copies -- so, one on your Mac, one on our PC, one on the remote server -- and you can update any one of these, which I think meets your requirement (b).

Both systems -- indeed, any version control system -- will let you revert back to a previous state.  That's why we do version control.

Both systems provide a mechanism for "exporting" the current state of the repository (e.g., `git archive` or `svn export`).  So that's (d).

You may want to investigate [Sparkleshare](http://sparkleshare.org/), which is a Dropbox clone that uses Git as it's backing store.  If you run Sparkleshare on your Mac and PC and do your development in this folder, then you get automatic synchronization.

You could also simply put your working copy inside your Dropbox folder, if you're already using Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

I've used David Winter's ["Install and manage WordPress with Git"](http://davidwinter.me/articles/2012/04/09/install-and-manage-wordpress-with-git/) with great success.

The core WordPress files are maintained as a sub-repository, making updates and such a lot easier to manage.

One thing that I do a little differently is that I actually include `wp-config.php` in the repo, and just move the database user/password/server and salts to a different, untracked, file. This makes deploying an install to a new server very simple - I just have to add the database information and I'm ready to go.

I would think twice about keeping your MySQL database in Git.  That's usually not supposed to be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So if keeping MySQL db in Git is bad practice, is there another way to push changes between different servers?

Comment: I usually manually export/import using phpmyadmin, but that is admittedly pretty cumbersome.  Here's a question on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6240581/keep-mysql-schema-in-sync-between-computers

Comment: ah. thanks. i keep thinking these two processes should go together, but 2 different workflows works as well.

Answer (score 0):

- You **have to read docs** anyway for selected SCM
- Git (as DVCS) will be *somehow* better in your case (no needs for repository-server)

Tasks

a) enable server on remote side, pull|push changes from|to (you always commit to local repo and have to publish changes to another host)

b) Git can have any amount of remotes, one of it can be client's repository. See p. a)

c) Check the docs. It's SCM fundamentals for any VCS: `git checkout <HASH-ID>`

d) `git archive` will help